# Unexpected end of file bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, eof

```
lines=`grep -c "" List`
a=1
    while [$a -lt $lines] 
        do
            b=`sed "${a} q;d" List`
            a=$a+1
            echo $b
    done
```

So, I have this, what is supposed to take a line from a list and echo it.
Now, the while loop is not working(?) and returns me this error:`HARR.sh: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Spaces after `[` and before `]`:  `while [ $a -lt $lines ]` and `a=$a+1` -> `((a++))`.

Comment: @P.P. `++` works in some shells but it's not [required by the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), so `a=$((a+1))` is the more portable choice.

Comment: It would be useful to see some input + desired output, as running `sed` multiple times on the same file in a loop is probably unnecessary.

Comment: @TomFenech Question is tagged bash. Should be portable in bash at least ;-)

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ would tell you: add space after `[` and before `]`; use `$()` instead of legacy `\`\``; double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting, i.e., most things.

Comment: Note aside: if `lines` turns out to be a single line, your loop does not execute. Perhaps use `-le`?

Comment: also, why use grep to do wc's job?  `lines=$(wc -l <List)`  but then we could ask, why sed like that, instead of `sed -n "${a}p" List`

Comment: This is a ridiculously inefficient way to iterate over the lines of a file. `while IFS= read -r b; do ...; done < List` is all you need, assuming there is even a reason to iterate in `bash` rather than using some other program. Is`echo $b` your actual command, or just a placeholder for the real body of the loop?

Comment: echo $b is yes, a placeholder. There I want to call another program.

But I'm not sure of what to do then. I'm so new at all of this, and I need this done ASAP, so I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
#!/bin/bash
#
let a=1
while read line; do
    echo "$a $line"
    let a+=1
done < List
```

Comment: This could be better done as simply `nl List`, or even `cat -n List`...

Comment: `a` isn't even necessary; the number is only to select a line in the `sed` script, not to appear in the output.

Comment: Is not what I was looking for. I have a list of names, and i wanted it to echo  the name using a while, if possible.

Comment: Is this a class assignment?

Comment: No, I don't even have this subject.